# java.lang.OutOfMemory:Java heap space error in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, heap-memory, spark-submit

I am running Spark application using spark-submit and defined JVM parameters. With this set of parameters I get java heap space error:

```
EXTRA_JVM_FLAGS="-server -XX:+UseG1GC
                         -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=384m
                         -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2G
                         -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
     --master "local[4]"
     --driver-memory 2G
     --driver-java-options "${EXTRA_JVM_FLAGS}"
```

I tried to increase driver memory but it caused JVM crash. Also, I tried to increase max direct memory size which did not help in any way. What options should I change to fix heap space error?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the most basic option `-Xmx` - this is the max heap space size.
Code cache and direct memory size are native memory areas and don't affect the size of the heap.
By default, the JVM allocates 1/4 of RAM available on the box as max heap size. You can increase that if the machine is dedicated to the one JVM process pretty safely.

Comment: As far as I know, it works a bit different for Spark. Specifically, -Xmx is defined through the driver-memory option